# Would this be the correct way to punctuate this?

Tags: punctuation

I know a more common way would be to say something like,

> That crane is a beautiful animal, isn't it?

But if one were going to word it as follows:

> It's a beautiful animal, isn't it, that crane?

Would this be the proper way to punctuate the sentence?

Comment: I wouldn't say that version is incorrect, but I'd *leave the first comma out to reflect how I'd say it. It's neither essential for clarity nor advantageous for scanning. But the second comma can't be omitted. (*Normally, tag questions end a sentence, and should be set off with a comma.)

Comment: Both look fine to me. I’m forgetting what that second one is an example of. Lawler mentioned the technical term for it the other day, but I forget.

Comment: @tchrist Right dislocation.

Answer (score 1):

No it would not be *the* proper way. It would be *one* perfectly good way, among several others, such as “It’s a beautiful animal, isn’t it—that crane?”

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. So is "That crane--isn't it a beautiful animal?" There are probably even more ways to phrase the sentence, but your first example is probably the clearest.